# How to keep count of how many times an article has been seen as fulltext or introtext-alone?

Tags: articles, statistics

Joomla core articles hits counter only works when the full article is shown (fulltext).

But if only the introtext is displayed, like in a Category Blog view or in a Featured Articles Blog view, the hit counter doesn't work.

This is a very limited behaviour, especially since many times we don't even use the "read more" button and the whole article is shown in the "introtext".

So **I would like to count how many times an article has been shown** (in full view, or just as part of a category blog view or a featured articles view).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a plugin which was triggered by an event such as onContentPrepare, like this:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentHits extends JPlugin
{
     public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
     {
        $parts = explode(".", $context);
        if (isset($parts[0]) && $parts[0] == "com_content" && isset($parts[1]) && $parts[1] != "article" && isset($article->id))
        {
            $table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
            $table->hit($article->id);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

You can use the `$context` to check that it's com_content (rather than com_contact for example), and what view is being shown. You have to not count a hit if it's a single article, because that's counted by default.

I haven't debugged this approach fully, but you may be able to use it as the basis for a solution.

Comment: FYI, `isset()` can receive multiple parameters.  Since you are using all `&&` in your conditional expression, you can condense it to: `if (isset($article->id, $parts[0], $parts[1]) && $parts[0] == "com_content" && $parts[1] != "article")`  Another technique would be to use a regular expression instead of exploding if so inclined (maybe something akin to: https://regex101.com/r/4Pg4mx/1).

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, I didn't realise that - useful to know!

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure you want to check for com_content. I may be reading too much into it, but the OP seems to want a count of how many times the introtext was shown to a user, and a module could still display the introtext on any page at all. And then there are independent components like K2 or the like that could be displaying it.